# Grouping timestamps and graphing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have a dataframe like so

```
PersonId  TimeStamp
10        2023-03-11 02:22:25
1         2023-03-30 03:02:20
26        2023-01-11 08:02:28
28        2023-02-26 09:25:01
46        2023-01-27 11:49:40
2         2023-04-01 01:32:21
```

I want to plot this with the timestamp on the x-axis and counts for every person in a certain range.

I want to group by every week or every month in a function. How can I do this in python?

I have the following code:

```
series = df.groupby(df.TimeStamp.dt.to_period('W'))[[PersonId]].count().reset_index()
```

I get an error when I plot here and don't know why

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,6))
ax.plot(series.TimeStamp, series.SubmissionID)
# float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'
```

Comment: `ax = dfg.plot(x='TimeStamp', kind='bar', figsize=(8, 6))` best to use the the `pandas` plotting API directly. And it should be a bar plot, because it's discrete data. `dfg = df.groupby(df.TimeStamp.dt.to_period('W'))[['PersonId']].count().reset_index()` because `df.groupby(...)[['PersonId']].count().reset_index()` is not a series, it's a dataframe.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney When I plot the dates they show as a range. Is it possible to only show the first day of that week?

Comment: Maybe `dfg.TimeStamp = dfg.TimeStamp.dt.start_time.dt.date` before plotting

Answer (score 0):

Try to plot directly:

```
# MS for month starts
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='TimeStamp', freq='MS'))['PersonId'].size().plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

**Note**: for week, use `freq='W'`:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='TimeStamp', freq='W'))['PersonId'].size().plot.bar()
```